# Corrupted workbook created, when trying to create one using ms-graph APIs

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api, excel-online

I am trying to create a new Workbook inside my OneDrive, using the following API call :

HTTP request:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/<path>:/children
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "name": "NewBook.xlsx",
  "file": { },
  "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior": "rename"
}
```

This creates a new workbook in the one drive.
But, when I try to open it (`from the OneDrive UI`), it shows that the **excel file is corrupted**.
Contrary to that, when I try to create a new `.txt` or `.pptx` or `.docx` and then try to access that, **it is easily accessible.**
**The API call that I am making here, is not present in the official MS-Graph API reference. It was a hit and trial done, and it worked. But the file being created is corrupted only in case of `Excel.`**

- If the creation of workbook is not allowed, can anyone provide me
  with the links as to where it is officially mentioned?
- If its allowed, then what changes do i need to make in the current API call?

Comment: Link to ms-graph api reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/?view=graph-rest-1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found a way to create a workbook using `ms-graph-api`. Although creation of workbook is not allowed, i did a bit of tweaking, to create a new workbook with the specific name.

1) Using [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/), created a new workbook locally.
2) Uploaded the workbook, with the specified name.